# Chromeless - get all images src from a webpage

Tags: image, html-parsing, chromeless

I'm trying to get the src values for all img tags in an HTML page using Chromeless. My current implementation is something like this:

```
async function run() {
    const chromeless = new Chromeless();
    let url = 'http://someurl/somepath.html';

    var allImgUrls = await chromeless
        .goto(url)
        .evaluate(() => document.getElementsByTagName('img'));

    var htmlContent = await chromeless
        .goto(url)
        .evaluate(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML );

    console.log(allImgUrls);

    await chromeless.end()
}
```

The issue is, I'm not getting any values of img object in the `allImgUrls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, found out that we could use this approach:

```
var imgSrcs = await chromeless
        .goto(url)
        .evaluate(() => {
            /// since document.querySelectorAll doesn't actually return an array but a Nodelist (similar to array)
            /// we call the map function from Array.prototype which is equivalent to [].map.call()
            const srcs = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'), img => img.src);
            return JSON.stringify(srcs);
        });
```